# Find the 2nd order Taylor Polynomial of $y(x)$ about $x = 0$, given $y^3 + y^2 + y - 3 = x$

Tags: solution-verification, taylor-expansion

I am given the equation:

$$y^3 + y^2 + y - 3 = x$$

with $y(0)=1$. I am wondering if what I have done is valid, given that this is a homework question for an Integral Calculus class, but I seem to be able to answer the question without doing any integration.

Taking the derivative of both sides (and using implicit differentiation) with respect to $x$ and then rearranging, I have

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left(y^3 + y^2 + y - 3\right) = \frac{d}{dx}(x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{3y^2 + 2y + 1}$$

So, since I am given $y(0) = 1$, I have my first two terms in the Taylor Series: $f(0) = 1$, and now $f'(0) = \frac{1}{6}$, since $y = 1$ when $x = 0$.

I then take the 2nd derivative with respect to $x$ (and again using implicit differentiation) to get$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = - \frac{y'(x)(6y+2)}{(3y^2 + 2y + 1)^2} .$$

Plugging in for $y$ and $y'$, when $x = 0$, I get $y''(0) = - \frac{1}{27}$.

Therefore my Taylor polynomial of order 2, about $x = 0$, is$$1 + \frac{x}{6} - \frac{x^2}{27} .$$

Is this correct?

I appreciate any tips and advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor error, recall that we need to divide by $2!$ at $x^2$ (and so on). The Taylor expansion about $x=a$ up to the $(x-a)^n$ term goes like this:
$$f(a)+\frac{f'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+ \cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n.$$

You got after differentiating once,
$$(3y^2+2y+1)\frac{dy}{dx}=1.$$
To find the second derivative, I prefer not to divide, it sometimes makes a mess. The above expression  looks nice, might as well just differentiate as it stands. We get 
$$(3y^2+2y+1)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ (6y+2)\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2=0,$$
and now we can find the second derivative at $0$. It does indeed simplify to $-1/27$.

Comment: Thank you! I did forget the 2!

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative**:

As a first approximation, let $y=a$ be a constant and match it to the constant term in $x$:

$$a^3+a^2+a-3\to0.$$

We have the solution $a=1$.

Then try a linear approximation and identify the first order terms:

$$(bx+1)^3+(bx+1)^2+(bx+1)-3=\cdots+3bx+2bx+bx\cdots\to x,$$giving $b=\frac16$.

Then add a second degree term, and

$$(cx^2+\frac x6+1)^3+(cx^2+\frac x6+1)^2+(cx^2+\frac x6+1)-3=\\\cdots+3cx^2+\frac{x^2}{12}+2cx^2+\frac{x^2}{18}+cx^2\cdots\to0x^2,$$or $c=-\frac1{54}$.

$$y\approx1+\frac x6-\frac{x^2}{54}\cdots.$$

This coincides with the Taylor development.